# Real-time whiteboard synchroniser between Android and Desktop

Tags: android, linux, synchronization, whiteboard

As COVID-19 forced millions to set up their home office, I still feel the absence of a simple whiteboard is one of the biggest barriers in Zoom, Team or Slack... whatever name you.

So I wondered if there is any app that can leverage my tablet (a galaxy A7 with an S-pen) where I can doodle a figure and it synchronises real time with my laptop screen which I share via zoom? I usually run Linux (Ubuntu or Manjaro) on my laptop, so best if the app supports Android and Linux.

The synching can happen via some online account, or bluetooth or connected to the same wifi, whatever. I like the KDE plasma desktop and their KDE connect comes close to connecting the devices, but from what I know, not there yet.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket this is Software Recommendations SE., correct?

Comment: Yes.  You posted on Android Enthusiasts SE and I requested your post to be migrated here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MIRO](https://miro.com/) web site, it is not exactly white board you you can do it. Also [Draw](https://draw.io/) web site can help if you want to make diagrams.

About pure whiteboard you can add this option in Teams, but you should activate it and install [specific software](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-whiteboard).